# Leaving space for solutions under questions

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I want to prepare a booklet for students in which they have questions and right amount of space under them.

I am using article class, and my questions are like this:

```
\begin{question}
question comes here
\end{question}
```

Is it possible to make something like

```
\begin{question}[3]
question comes here
\end{question}
```

So that there is a 1/3 page space under the question.

I think the important point here is that

```
\begin{question}[2]
if this question is at the top of the page
\end{question}

\begin{question}[3]
this question comes below it
\end{question}

\begin{question}[2]
and this one should be on a new page
\end{question}
```

**Edit:** In fact, I can just add something like \vspace{5cm} below questions, but there is a possibility that the question appears on the bottom of the page and its space is on the next page. I don't want that.

Comment: Are you constrained to use the article class? The [exam class](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam?lang=en) by Philip Hirschhorn makes it easy to generate consistent spacing between questions.

Comment: What does `[2]` represent if `[3]` is `1/3`? `1/2`?

Comment: @Werner yes, exactly

Comment: @ThePortakal: What should be the default space below a `question`? Is there a possibility for you to add the definition of the `question` environment to your post?

Comment: Note that with the current requirement, you will *not* have two `\begin{question}[2]` on the same page, nor three `\begin{question}[3]` => waste of space. Speaking of `\begin{question}`, the `exsheets` package has an interesting option for the vertical space `\examspace*<dim>`-- if the empty space is a bit longer than the space available, it can trim what would normally go on the next page (which is the default setting) -- this would give a flexibile (shrinkable) 1/2, 1/3 page.

Comment: try with [needspace package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace)

Comment: @Werner I used \newtheorem{question}{Question} that comes with amsthm package I guess

Comment: You can use minipages to keep the Q and the \vspace in one block, or mdframed (with no frame/spacing and no page breaks), or ...

Comment: I would use the \vspace tag, which allows you to put as much vertical space as you want between lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `minipage` with calculated height:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\mylen}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{quest}{Question} 
\newenvironment{question}[1][2]{% the \dimexpr calculation is from:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383689/101651
    \setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\numexpr\textheight*1/#1\relax sp\relax}\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\mylen][t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{quest}}
    {\end{quest} 
    \end{minipage}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{question}[2]
if this question is at the top of the page
\end{question}

\begin{question}[3]
this question comes below it
\end{question}

\begin{question}[2]
and this one should be on a new page
\end{question}

\begin{question}[10]
$\frac{1}{10}$ text height question
\end{question} 

\begin{question}[5]
$\frac{1}{5}$ text height question
\end{question} 

\begin{question}
I used ``2'' as default, so you can also omit it.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]